# Stored procedure call fails with "Feature not supported" error

Tags: jdbc, oracle11g, eclipselink

I have the following piece of code which has stopped working after our DB (Oracle 12c) was patched. The JDBC driver being used in ojdbc6.

```
Calendar durationDate = Calendar.getInstance();
StoredProcedureCall procedureCall = new StoredProcedureCall();
procedureCall.setProcedureName("bpm_wrap_colo_ext_pkg.business_date");
procedureCall.addNamedArgument("p_country_code");

procedureCall.addNamedArgument("p_atcws_lookup_tbl", "p_atcws_lookup_tbl",
        OracleTypes.ARRAY, "GBL_EXT_TBL");
procedureCall.addNamedCursorOutputArgument("p_business_date");



DataReadQuery query = new DataReadQuery();
query.setCall(procedureCall);
query.addArgument("p_country_code");
query.addArgument("p_atcws_lookup_tbl");
query.dontCacheStatement();

List<Object[]> durationData = new ArrayList<Object[]>();
durationData.add(toAarry(durationDays));

Vector args = new Vector();
args.addElement(countryCode);
args.addElement(durationData.toArray());

Session session =
        JpaHelper.getEntityManager(em).getActiveSession();

List<DatabaseRecord> list =
        (List<DatabaseRecord>)session.executeQuery(query, args);
```

The exception I am getting is:

> <2018-07-22 09:08:24.416--UnitOfWork(759992210)--Exception
>   [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services -
>   2.3.1.v20111018-r10243): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException Internal
>   Exception: java.sql.SQLException: Unsupported feature Error Code:
>   17023 Call: BEGIN
>   atc_bpm_wrap_colo_ext_pkg.business_date(p_country_code=>?,
>   p_atcws_lookup_tbl=>?, p_business_date=>?); END;  bind => [3
>   parameters bound] Query: DataReadQuery()>  Exception while getting
>   duration from ebs Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException:
>   Unsupported feature Error Code: 17023 Call: BEGIN
>   XXATC.atc_bpm_wrap_colo_ext_pkg.business_date(p_country_code=>?,
>   p_atcws_lookup_tbl=>?, p_business_date=>?); END;  bind => [3
>   parameters bound] Query: DataReadQuery() Local Exception Stack: 
>   Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services -
>   2.3.1.v20111018-r10243): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException Internal
>   Exception: java.sql.SQLException: Unsupported feature Error Code:
>   17023 Call: BEGIN
>   XXATC.atc_bpm_wrap_colo_ext_pkg.business_date(p_country_code=>?,
>   p_atcws_lookup_tbl=>?, p_business_date=>?); END;  bind => [3
>   parameters bound] Query: DataReadQuery()  at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException.sqlException(DatabaseException.java:333)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.basicExecuteCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:644)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:535)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.basicExecuteCall(AbstractSession.java:1717)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.server.ServerSession.executeCall(ServerSession.java:566)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:207)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:193)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeSelectCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:264)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeSelect(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:246)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DataReadQuery.executeNonCursor(DataReadQuery.java:197)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DataReadQuery.executeDatabaseQuery(DataReadQuery.java:152)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.execute(DatabaseQuery.java:844)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DataReadQuery.execute(DataReadQuery.java:137)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.executeInUnitOfWork(DatabaseQuery.java:743)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.internalExecuteQuery(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:2871)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1516)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1498)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1463)
>     at
>   com.atc.ebs.model.facade.EBSModelDAO.getDurationDate(EBSModelDAO.java:758)
>     at
>   com.atc.ebs.model.facade.EBSSessionEJBBean.getDueDate(EBSSessionEJBBean.java:456)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)     at
>   com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:310)
>     at
>   com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:182)
>     at
>   com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:149)
>     at
>   com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:131)
>     at
>   com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:119)
>     at
>   com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
>     at
>   com.oracle.pitchfork.spi.MethodInvocationVisitorImpl.visit(MethodInvocationVisitorImpl.java:34)
>     at
>   weblogic.ejb.container.injection.EnvironmentInterceptorCallbackImpl.callback(EnvironmentInterceptorCallbackImpl.java:54)
>     at
>   com.oracle.pitchfork.spi.EnvironmentInterceptor.invoke(EnvironmentInterceptor.java:42)
>     at
>   com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
>     at
>   com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:89)
>     at
>   com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
>     at
>   com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:131)
>     at
>   com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:119)
>     at
>   com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
>     at
>   com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
>     at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy719.getDueDate(Unknown Source)   at
>   com.atc.ebs.model.facade.EBSSessionEJB_97b7qo_EBSSessionEJBImpl.__WL_invoke(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   weblogic.ejb.container.internal.SessionRemoteMethodInvoker.invoke(SessionRemoteMethodInvoker.java:40)
>     at
>   com.atc.ebs.model.facade.EBSSessionEJB_97b7qo_EBSSessionEJBImpl.getDueDate(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   com.atc.ebs.model.facade.EBSSessionEJB_97b7qo_EBSSessionEJBImpl_WLSkel.invoke(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   weblogic.rmi.internal.ServerRequest.sendReceive(ServerRequest.java:174)
>     at
>   weblogic.rmi.cluster.ClusterableRemoteRef.invoke(ClusterableRemoteRef.java:347)
>     at
>   weblogic.rmi.cluster.ClusterableRemoteRef.invoke(ClusterableRemoteRef.java:261)
>     at
>   com.atc.ebs.model.facade.EBSSessionEJB_97b7qo_EBSSessionEJBImpl_1036_WLStub.getDueDate(Unknown
>   Source)   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
>   Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)     at
>   weblogic.ejb.container.internal.RemoteBusinessIntfProxy.invoke(RemoteBusinessIntfProxy.java:89)
>     at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy718.getDueDate(Unknown Source)   at
>   com.atc.pw.emea.task.BaseTaskValidation.taskInitiate(BaseTaskValidation.java:163)
>     at
>   com.atc.pw.emea.task.BaseTaskValidation.validateTaskOperation(BaseTaskValidation.java:49)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)     at
>   oracle.bpel.services.workflow.task.impl.TaskValidationCallbackInvoker.executeJavaCallback(TaskValidationCallbackInvoker.java:191)
>     at
>   oracle.bpel.services.workflow.task.impl.TaskValidationCallbackInvoker.performCallbacks(TaskValidationCallbackInvoker.java:104)
>     at
>   oracle.bpel.services.workflow.task.impl.TaskService.initiateTask(TaskService.java:1345)
>     at
>   oracle.bpel.services.workflow.task.impl.TaskService.initiateTask(TaskService.java:807)
>     at
>   oracle.bpel.services.workflow.task.impl.TaskService.initiateTask(TaskService.java:735)
>     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor5155.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)     at
>   org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:307)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:182)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:149)
>     at
>   oracle.bpel.services.workflow.common.WorkflowFabricInitCheckAdvice.invoke(WorkflowFabricInitCheckAdvice.java:26)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
>     at
>   oracle.bpel.services.workflow.common.WorkflowServiceCacheEventAdvice.invoke(WorkflowServiceCacheEventAdvice.java:113)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
>     at
>   oracle.bpel.services.workflow.test.workflow.ExceptionTestCaseBuilder.invoke(ExceptionTestCaseBuilder.java:155)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
>     at
>   oracle.bpel.services.common.dms.MethodEventAspect.invoke(MethodEventAspect.java:70)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
>     at
>   oracle.bpel.services.common.dms.MethodPhaseEventAspect.invoke(MethodPhaseEventAspect.java:82)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
>     at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy366.initiateTask(Unknown Source)     at
>   oracle.bpel.services.workflow.task.ejb.TaskServiceBean.initiateTask(TaskServiceBean.java:70)
>     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor5156.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)     at
>   com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:310)
>     at
>   com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:182)
>     at
>   com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:149)
>     at
>   com.oracle.pitchfork.intercept.MethodInvocationInvocationContext.proceed(MethodInvocationInvocationContext.java:103)
>     at
>   oracle.security.jps.ee.ejb.JpsAbsInterceptor$1.run(JpsAbsInterceptor.java:135)
>     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)   at
>   oracle.security.jps.util.JpsSubject.doAs(JpsSubject.java:213)     at
>   oracle.security.jps.ee.util.JpsPlatformUtil.runJaasMode(JpsPlatformUtil.java:458)
>     at
>   oracle.security.jps.ee.ejb.JpsAbsInterceptor.runJaasMode(JpsAbsInterceptor.java:122)
>     at
>   oracle.security.jps.ee.ejb.JpsAbsInterceptor.intercept(JpsAbsInterceptor.java:193)
>     at
>   oracle.security.jps.ee.ejb.JpsInterceptor.intercept(JpsInterceptor.java:113)
>     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor2645.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)     at
>   com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:310)
>     at
>   com.oracle.pitchfork.intercept.JeeInterceptorInterceptor.invoke(JeeInterceptorInterceptor.java:68)
>     at
>   com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
>     at
>   com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:131)
>     at
>   com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:119)
>     at
>   com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
>     at
>   com.oracle.pitchfork.spi.MethodInvocationVisitorImpl.visit(MethodInvocationVisitorImpl.java:34)
>     at
>   weblogic.ejb.container.injection.EnvironmentInterceptorCallbackImpl.callback(EnvironmentInterceptorCallbackImpl.java:54)
>     at
>   com.oracle.pitchfork.spi.EnvironmentInterceptor.invoke(EnvironmentInterceptor.java:42)
>     at
>   com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
>     at
>   com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:89)
>     at
>   com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
>     at
>   com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:131)
>     at
>   com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:119)
>     at
>   com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
>     at
>   com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
>     at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy450.initiateTask(Unknown Source)     at
>   oracle.bpel.services.workflow.task.ejb.TaskServiceBean_ua8c6d_ELOImpl.__WL_invoke(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   weblogic.ejb.container.internal.SessionLocalMethodInvoker.invoke(SessionLocalMethodInvoker.java:39)
>     at
>   oracle.bpel.services.workflow.task.ejb.TaskServiceBean_ua8c6d_ELOImpl.initiateTask(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   oracle.bpel.services.workflow.task.client.TaskServiceLocalClient.initiateTask(TaskServiceLocalClient.java:43)
>     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor5155.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)     at
>   oracle.bpel.services.workflow.client.WFClientRetryInvocationHandler.invokeTarget(WFClientRetryInvocationHandler.java:144)
>     at
>   oracle.bpel.services.workflow.client.WFClientRetryInvocationHandler.invoke(WFClientRetryInvocationHandler.java:82)
>     at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy708.initiateTask(Unknown Source)     at
>   oracle.bpel.services.workflow.task.impl.TaskServiceWSIF.initiateTask(TaskServiceWSIF.java:192)
>     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor5154.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)     at
>   oracle.bpel.services.workflow.fabric.WorkflowServiceEngine.request(WorkflowServiceEngine.java:1434)
>     at
>   oracle.integration.platform.blocks.mesh.SynchronousMessageHandler.doRequest(SynchronousMessageHandler.java:139)
>     at
>   oracle.integration.platform.blocks.mesh.MessageRouter.request(MessageRouter.java:182)
>     at
>   oracle.integration.platform.blocks.mesh.MeshImpl$2.run(MeshImpl.java:225)
>     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)   at
>   javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)    at
>   oracle.integration.platform.blocks.mesh.MeshImpl.doRequestAsSubject(MeshImpl.java:223)
>     at
>   oracle.integration.platform.blocks.mesh.MeshImpl.request(MeshImpl.java:195)

Any help is much appreciated!

Thanks,
Rahul

Comment: This is a database error running a database stored procedure after you've patched the database - shouldn't you mention the database involved and tag the DB appropriately? If you think it is the JDBC, maybe include the driver and version you are using?

Comment: You are right, my bad. I have added the information.